# Разбитие youtube видео на части

Tags: битрикс, cms, интерфейс, youtube, видео

Как youtube видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY2gR8Uvdrk&list=PLrHjm4aMLlqKmIGolcjzSL94gF2JnBGPH&index=5 разбить на части (на уже **существующие** - **созданные автором видео**)?

Comment: И где же там созданные автором части?

Comment: @Qwertiy в этом видео похоже нет. Но вообще после **каких действий** отображаются тайм коды для видео?

Comment: Если они есть в описании (вроде ещё вариант с первым комментарием есть) и начальный тайм-код - ноль. Впрочем, что-то они сломали и сей1час оно не работает...

Comment: @Qwertiy я помню, что я на что-то нажимал и в результате отображались тайм-коды (на полосе прокрутки видео). Только не помню на что.